# subseting dataframe conditions on factor(binary) column(vector in r language)

Tags: r, conditional-statements, subset, markov-chains, markov

i have a sequence of 1/0's indicating if patient is in remission or not,

assume the records of remission or not were taken at discrete times,

how can  i check the markov property for each patient, then summarize the findings, that is the assumption that the probability of remission for any patient at any time depends only if the patient had remission the last time/not remission last time(same as thing as saying probability of remission for any patient at any time depends only if the patient had remission in the previous row, well if not first observation)

P(r=1 at t=t+1|r=1 at t)=p(r=1 at t+1|r=1 at t, r=0 at t=t-1, r=1 at t=t-2, r=1 at t=t-3)

easy to understand if you understand the markov property

this is an exercept of my df

patientId   remission

```
ju67       1

ju67       0

ju67       0

ju88       1

ju88       1

ju23       1

ju23       0
```

any ideas? subsetting the dataframe with the required condtions then computing probabilities using 'msm' package or (probably better way) just viewing the state transitions table will work but how do i do this, for the subsets of dataframe i would need for example to include only patients with three consecutive 0's in remission(including 0 in remission now) and compare this to subset of a dataframe with two consecutive 0's in remission(including 0 in remission now) –

Comment: This is a better question for [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) as this is a statistics and not a programming question.   In fact [similar questions](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29490/test-for-markov-property-in-a-time-series) have been asked and answered on that site.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i don't think the markov property is too advanced statistics any ideas to test the markov assumption?

Comment: Your attempt at building a mathematical expression seems garbled which is further evidence that you should first go to CV.com. (Easy to see if one does understand the Markov property.)

Comment: lol i simply missed out r=1 in the begininng of my probability statement, anyways, any ideas? subsetting the dataframe with the required condtions then computing probabilities using 'msm' package will work but how do i do this, for the subsets of dataframe i would need for example to include only patients with three consecutive 0's in remission(including 0 in remission now) and compare this to subset of a dataframe with two consecutive 0's in remission(including 0 in remission now)